# prepaid meters that rely on a disconnected system

Tags: des, encryption

i have some experience with cryptography in the banking sectors, mostly in block ciphers like DES 3DES etc. im interested in prepaid electricity meters as it is a number that is generated from a central system which is disconnected from the meter its self.

This would mean they are using a symmetric algorithm using the device meter number and the "recharge" value to make it unique. so i presume there would be a secret key stored on the device of which they have the clear component in order to create the recharge token. similar to an HSM and its LMK. The tokens are 16 digits which in its self would make brute force difficult as you dont know the transformations performed on the input.

i was thinking about how ciphers where "broken" during the mid 1950's, how would someone analyse cyphertext without knowledge of the algorithm or the clear text content ?

*just in case anyone thinks i'm going to try and do it. i'm not,its a question based on curiosity*

Comment: Why would it "mean they are using a" _symmetric_ algorithm? $\;$

Comment: an assumption, im open to ideas. it cant be public/ private and asymetric dosnt fit the architecture of one server sending to many clients

Comment: Why doesn't asymmetric "fit the architecture of [one server sending to many clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)"? $\hspace{1.29 in}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography so the server would have to maintain public keys for all of the meters ?

Comment: @user2168435 I fail to see how that article supports your point. Read the article Ricky linked on digital signatures -- encryption is irrelevant here anyway, because there's no reason for the amount added to be secret (what matters is that no one can fake an amount).

Comment: as froml the link you sent " A digital signature is a mathematical scheme for demonstrating the authenticity of a digital message or document." which is the authenticity of the data not necessarily the encryption of the data. unless you were referring to RSA which is public private. My question is not so much of what algoritim they are using but how a cipher would be decoded without understanding the algorithm

Comment: There are just too many schemes possible with an online protocol. Maybe if you could specify the specific products/protocols that somebody knows the answer. But as this is pretty domain specific you would have to be rather lucky. Maybe you could ask a vendor.

Comment: The "without knowing the algorithm" is a classical (and today wrong) point of view. One reason for making that assumption might be, that security understanding of the banking sector is most of the time decades behind current standards (which are also a few years behind current research). Knowing the algorithm involved is the very basic ability we grant any serious attacker. Any weaker attacker is irrelevant today.